# Why are these members not being default initialized?

Tags: c++

In the following code, I get these warning messages:

> Member 'year' was not initialized in this constructor
>
> Member 'month'was not initialized in this constructor
>
> Member 'day' was not initialized in this constructor
>
> ...

However, I would expect the members to be default initialized to, say, 0 for the uint32_t types.

```
typedef uint32_t bmd2_uint32;

class UnitTestCInterface : public UnitTest {
{
  private:
    bmd2_uint32 year;
    bmd2_uint32 month;
    bmd2_uint32 day;
    ...
  
  public:
    UnitTestCInterface() 
      : filename(nullptr), UnitTest("UNIT TEST: C Interface") { };
```

How come these members aren't being default initialized, and what can I do about it?

Comment: what can I do about it: you could initialize them.

Comment: "However, I would expect the members to be default initialized to, say, 0 for the uint32_t types" That's just not what C++ does.

Comment: sarcasm aside, C++ does not say fundamental types have intrinsic initializer called implicitely. so you need to call uint32_t() explicitely to get a zero. Also static storage will fill things with zero.

Comment: The only way to get primitive types "auto-initialized" is to declare them `static` or `global` - in that case they will be set to zero when the code is loaded (as their memory is allocated at the time the program loads, not during run time). For all other cases you have to do the hard work yourself.

Comment: What if there is a default constructor?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be default initialized to zero?

Comment: I think I confused myself with user-defined types which are default constructed.  I am learning a lot about C++ but I do keep forgetting a basic point here and there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize them using an initialization list:

```
UnitTestCInterface() 
      : year(0),month(0),day(0), filename(nullptr), UnitTest("UNIT TEST: C Interface")
     { };
```

Comment: two `:` ? and beware of order

Comment: Can I use the body of the constructor?

Comment: @billz, Good catch. I should have been more careful.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues, You can do whatever you want in the constructor, including assignment of members, but I believe it is standard practice to use the initialization lists.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: As a general rule, use an initializer list (as shown in this answer) on the constructor to initialize a class's data members. If you assign a value in the body of the constructor, it is just that--assignment--rather than initialization. That is not a problem in your sample code, but if you had const or reference members, the only way to give them a value would be through an initializer list because you cannot assign to them.